# i want to flip between two images by clicking on the image itself using javascript

Tags: javascript, image

i want to flip between two images by clicking on the image itself. help me with the code(i want the most simplified answer, very new learner)

```
function changeImage(){
        var img = document.createElement('img')
            img.src =="images/pic2.jpg"
        let displayImage = document.getElementById('first')
        if (displayImage.getAttribute("src") =="images/pic.jpg") {
            
            document.getElementById('first').appendChild(img);
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change the `src` attribute of the image.

```js
function switchImage () {
  let element = document.getElementById("myImg")
  if (element.src == "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a7/Chamomile%40original_size.jpg/367px-Chamomile%40original_size.jpg") {
    element.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f1/Aquilegia_vulgaris_100503c.jpg/420px-Aquilegia_vulgaris_100503c.jpg"
  } else {
    element.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a7/Chamomile%40original_size.jpg/367px-Chamomile%40original_size.jpg"
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="myImg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a7/Chamomile%40original_size.jpg/367px-Chamomile%40original_size.jpg" onclick="switchImage()" />
```

Comment: FYI, you don't have to set `src` attribute, you can directly set/get via image property: `element.src`

Comment: Thanks, @vanowm, I switched to that method.